# How many squares can be constructed on a square grid of points?

Tags: combinatorics, analytic-geometry

Let $C = \{(i, j)|i, j \in \mathbb Z,\; 0 ≤ i, j ≤ 24\}$.

How many squares can be formed in the
plane all of whose vertices are in $C$ and whose sides are parallel to the $x$−axis and $y$−axis?

This question recently came up in the [Mathematics chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63317847#63317847).  While it is a problem statement question, I think that it is an intrinsically interesting problem (at the very least, I got sucked in).  I also think that this is the kind of problem which can be given to a clever high school student or undergraduate and that, as such, it deserves a place on the site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  The problem has been asked before, for instance, [Given an $n \times n$ grid, how many squares exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942364/given-an-n-times-n-grid-how-many-squares-exist?rq=1).  That said, the hypotheses are more clearly stated here.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for finding it---can I ask what search terms you used? I had little luck with both Google and Approach0.