# Given an $n \times n $ grid, how many squares exist?

Tags: combinatorics

How many squares exist in an $n \times n$ grid?  There are obviously $n^2$ small squares, and $4$ squares of size $(n-1) \times (n-1)$.

How can I go about counting the number of squares of each size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to view this: for each size, there is one square that you move inside the larger one.

How much can it move? A square of size $k\times k$ inside a square of size $n\times n$ has $n-k+1$ possible positions in each direction (up-down and left-right): consider the position of the top left corner for instance. Hence there are $(n-k+1)^2$ such squares.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: What about the tilted squares? Like the square with coordinates $(0,1), (1,0),(2,1),$ and $(1,2)$?

Comment: @MikeEarnest This question is about the number of squares in a grid. The sides implicitly lie on the grid, so there are no "tilted" squares. If you have a question about a more general case, you should creat a new question.

Comment: I get it now. I was envisioning the grid to just be an array of $n^2$ points, but I see everyone else is interpreting "grid" to also include the $2n$ lines.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You can count the number of squares of unit side. Now go on increasing the sied of the square (to 2 then 3 and so on) and count the number of squares. To make things easier there are $24^2$ number of unit squares and 1 square with side 24. Find the rest of the middle values, and add them up.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of counting:

For each
$(i, j, k)$
with
$1 \le i, j \le n$
and
$0 \le k \le \min(n-i, n-j)$
there is a square
with upper left corner
at $(i, j)$
and lower right corner at
$(i+k, j+k)$.

Therefore the total is

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (1+\min(n-i, n-j))\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (1+\min(i, j))\\
&=n^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \min(i, j)\\
&=n^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \min(i, j)+\sum_{j=i} \min(i, j)+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \min(i, j))\\
&=n^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} j+i+\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} i)\\
&=n^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\frac12i(i-1)+i+i(n-1-(i+1)+1))\\
&=n^2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\binom{i}{2}+i+i(n-i-1))\\
&=n^2+\binom{n}{3}+\frac12 n(n-1)+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (ni-i(i+1))\\
&=n^2+\binom{n}{3}+\frac12 n(n-1)+\frac12 n^2(n-1)-\sum_{i=1}^{n} i(i-1)\\
&=n^2+\binom{n}{3}+\frac12 n(n-1)+\frac12 n^2(n-1)-2\binom{n+1}{3}\\
&=\frac13(n+1)n(n-1)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Let the vertices of the $n \times n$ grid by $\{(x,y)| 0\le x \le n; 0 \le y \le n\}$.

(Is that what an $n \times n$ grid is?  A $1 \times 1$ has **$4$** vertices and an $n \times n$ grid has $(n+1)^2$ vertices?  Or is a $1 \times 1$ grid a single point?  I'm assuming the former.)

A $k \times k$ square will have an lower left hand vertex as $(x,y)$ and a upper right hand vertex at $(x+k, y+k)$ with the stipulation $0 \le x; 0 \le y; x+k \le n; y+k \le n$ or in other words: $0 \le x \le n-k; 0 \le y \le n-k$.

There are $n-k+1$ possible options for $x$ and $n-k+1$ options for $y$ so there $(n-k+1)^2$ $k\times k$ squares.

So the total number of squares is $\sum{k=1}^n(n-k+1)^2$.  Let $j = n-k+1$ and we have #squares = $\sum_{j = n;j--}^1j^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

Or to put it more simply.... A $k \times k$ square has a side of length $k$.  There are $n-(k-1)$ ways to choose this side from the grid that is $n$ long so for squares of lengths $1,2, ...., n$ there are $n, n-1....., 1$ way to choose the horizontal side and $n, n-1,...., 1$ ways to choose the vertical sides.  So there are $n^2, (n-1)^2,....., 1^2$ possible $1\times 1, 2\times 2, ...,n \times n$ squares. So there are $\sum k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$ total squares.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not the most elegant or efficient way to solve the problem, but it was my first thought.  The essential idea is to simply count the number of ordered triples $(i,j,\ell)$ which give us "valid" squares.

There are three choices to make:  first, choose the lower-left vertex (which requires two choices:  an $x$-coordinate and a $y$-coordinate), and then choose a side length.  In order to make the job slightly easier, assume that the $x$-coordinate is smaller than the $y$-coordinate.  Then, at the end, note that any square with lower-left vertex $(i,j)$ and side length $\ell$ can be reflected to get a square with lower-left vertex $(j,i)$ and side length $\ell$ (thus the total number is doubled).

Taking a more general approach, I will answer the following question:

> Let $C = \{ (i,j) \mid i,j\in\mathbb{N}_0, 0 \le i, j \le N \}$, where $N \in \mathbb{N}$.[1]  How many squares can be formed with sides parallel to the $x$- and $y$-axis, with vertices in $C$?

A possible approach is to make three choices:

1. choose the $x$-coordinate, $i$, of the lower-left vertex,
2. choose the $y$-coordinate, $j$, of the lower-left vertex, and
3. choose the side length, $\ell$, of the square.

To slightly simplify the reasoning, there are three cases which need to be considered:  $i < j$, $i=j$, and $i > j$.  The first and last cases are symmetric, so this reduces to counting the number of squares with $i < j$ and doubling it, and counting the number if squares with $i=j$.

- Assume that $i = j$.  The lower-left corner will be of the form $(i,i)$, where $i$ is an integer between $0$ and $N-1$ (inclusive).  Once the lower-left vertex is fixed, the upper-right vertex is $(i+\ell, i+\ell)$.  On the one hand, $\ell$ must be at least $1$.  On the other hand,
  $$ i + \ell \le 24 \implies \ell \le 24-i. $$
  Thus the total number of squares which can be constructed with $i=j$ is
  $$ \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \sum_{\ell=1}^{N-i} 1
  %= \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} (N-i)
  %= N^2 - \frac{1}{2}(N-1)N
  = \frac{1}{2} N (N+1).$$
- Assume that $i < j$.  The $x$-coordinate of the lower-left vertex, $i$, can be any integer from $0$ through $N-1$.  Once this coordinate is fixed, the $y$-coordinate, $j$, can be any integer from $i+1$ through $N-1$.  Finally, the side length, $\ell$, must be at least $1$, and must be chosen so that the upper-right vertex has both coordinates no larger than $N$.  This means that $\ell + j \le N$, from which it follows that $\ell < N - j$.  Thus the total number of squares which can be constructed with $i<j$ is
  \begin{align}
  \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{N-1} \sum_{\ell = 1}^{N-j} 1
  % I'll be honest---I worked this out by hand, then plugged it into WolframAlpha to check.  The computation is not hard, but is tedious, so I am going to elide it here entirely. 
  = \frac{1}{6} N(N^2-1) = \frac{1}{6}(N-1)N(N+1).
  \end{align}
  Double this to conclude that the total number of squares with $i\ne j$ is
  $$ \frac{1}{3} (N-1)N(N+1). $$

Therefore the total number of squares which can be constructed with sides parallel to the axes and vertices in the set $C$ is
$$ \frac{1}{2} N (N+1) + \frac{1}{3} (N-1)N(N+1)
%= N(N+1)\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}N-\frac{1}{3}\right)
= \frac{1}{6}N(N+1)(2N+1). $$

For example, with $N=3$, this gives
$$ \frac{1}{6}(3)(4)(7) = 14.$$
It is reasonably simple to verify by hand that this is correct:
[image]

In the question asked here, $N=24$.  Therefore there are
$$ \frac{1}{6}(24)(25)(49)
= 4900 $$
possible ways to construct squares with vertices parallel to the axes and coordinates between $0$ and $24$ (inclusive).

---

[1] For the purposes of this question, $0$ is not a natural number.  The set $\mathbb{N}_0$ denotes the set of natural numbers with zero, i.e. the set of nonnegative integers.

NB:  I have been [nerd-sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) by this question.  I also suspect that it has been duplicated, and that there is an answer on the site somewhere, but I can't find it.  So I am posting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be shown using induction.  To simplify the discussion, I will use the phrase "an $n\times n$ grid" to denote that set
$$ \{ (i,j) : i,j\in\mathbb{Z}, 0 \le i,j \le n \}. $$

> **Proposition:**  It is possible to construct $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^2$ squares in an $n\times n$ grid, where all of the squares have sides parallel to the axes.

*Proof:*  As a basis for induction, observe that when $n=1$, it is only possible to construct one square (i.e. the square with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$).  Note that
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{1} j^1 = 1, $$
which polishes off the base case.

For induction, suppose that it is possible to construct
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{k} j^2 \tag{IH}\label{ih}$$
squares in a $k\times k$ grid with sides parallel to the axes (note: this is labeled (\ref{ih}), as it is the induction hypothesis).

First observe that every square in a $k\times k$ grid is also a square in a $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ grid.  The only squares in the larger grid which are *not* counted here are those with a vertex which has either an $x$- or $y$-coordinate of $n$.  To count these, notice that for each choice of $(i,j)$ in the $k\times k$ grid, there is exactly one square with lower-left vertex $(i,j)$, and a vertex at either $(i,n)$ or $(n,j)$.  Thus expanding the grid by one unit in both directions adds a total of $(k+1)^2$ new squares (both $i$ and $j$ can be chosen freely between $0$ and $k$, inclusive).  Therefore the number of squares in a $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ grid is given by
$$ (\text{the number of squares in a $k\times k$ grid}) + (k+1)^2 \underset{\ref{ih}}{=} \left[\sum_{j=1}^{k} j^2\right] + (k+1)^2
= \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} j^2, $$
which is the desired result.

---

NB:  I have been [nerd-sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) by this question.  I also suspect that it has been duplicated, and that there is an answer on the site somewhere, but I can't find it.  So I am posting this answer.

Answer (score -2):

**NOTE:**

For $n\times n$ grid the answer is $n^2+(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2+.....+1^2$

So, the answer is 
$$
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$