# How many squares, including diagonal ones, can be drawn in an $n \times n$ dotted grid?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I know this question is quite often asked, and I got the answer myself quite easily:
$$ \frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6}$$
It is simply based on the summation of squares, like such:
$$1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+(n-1)^2$$
See more info in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942364/given-an-n-times-n-grid-how-many-squares-exist). The reason mine is $n-1$ specifically is it is a dotted grid.

Regardless, my question persists because in my specific case, I would like to include diagonal squares as well.

[image]

Sorry for the image(I don't really know how to draw shapes on Stack with $Latex$). I don't know how I am supposed to count the squares, including the diagonal ones, in a coordinate grid. It really puzzles me.

The much agreed answer apparently is:

$$\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}$$

Comment: [OEIS A002415](https://oeis.org/A002415) and [my old diagram](https://oeis.org/A002415/a002415.gif) are related

Comment: Thanks @Henry Is there a proof though?

Comment: A partial note: consider "upper-left" sides of the squares -- defined as the side with slope in [0,1) and above the other side with slope in [0,1). A square is determined by its upper left side.

There's $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n^2}{2} = \frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{4}$ possible upper-left sides (pick 2 endpts, half he time you'll have slope not in [0,1)). Issue is that some of the squares will spill over outside our grid. Based on the answer it seems exactly $\frac{2}{3}$ of the squares will spill outside the grid. Feels like there should be an intuitive way to see why this is, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each square is uniquely determined by $a,b$ where $a+b=n$ (in the picture in the question). This means that there are exactly $n-1$ possibilities if the diagonal square touches the sides of a $n\times n$ square with sides parallel to the grid lines. For each $1\leq k\leq n$, there are $(n-k+1)^2$ ways to find a $k\times k$ square subgrid of the $n\times n$ grid. The answer is therefore
$$ \begin{split}\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k+1)^2(k-1)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k(n-k)^2\\&=n^2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k-2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^2+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k^3\\&=n^2\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}2-2n\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}6+\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}4\\&=\frac1{12}n^2(n^2-1).\end{split} $$